# Namespaces with ECMAScript 6 classes

Tags: javascript, class, namespaces, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to define a class inside the namespace `TEST` using ECMAScript 6. With "old" Javascript I did this

```
var TEST=TEST || {};
TEST.Test1 = function() {
}
```

now I'm trying the following

```
var TEST=TEST || {};
class TEST.Test2 {

}
```

but I get an error over the dot between TEST and Test2

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

What's the correct way to do what I'm trying to accomplish, without using transpilers but only with native browser javascript?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just as for functions, there are *class declarations* and *class expressions*. You can use a class expression instead and assign the result to `TEST.Test1`:

```
TEST.Test1 = class { // or `TEST.Test1 = class Test1 {`

};
```

Comment: A named class expression might be even better!

Comment: @lonesomeday: Agreed.

Comment: Does this essentially act as both a namespace and a subclass?

Comment: @JacobStamm: There is no subclassing here (that would be `class foo extends bar {...}`. It's just a class that is assigned to a property. `TEST` acts as namespace I guess.

Comment: @FelixKling I actually thought that's what a subclass is: a class that is a member of another type. I didn't realize that a subclass and a derived class are the same thing. Thanks for the clarification. I suppose it could called a nested class or an inner class.

Comment: @JacobStamm: Ah, I see. I only know "subclass" as something that extends another class. Looks like it's all the same: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)#Subclasses_and_superclasses

Comment: Without `var` **Uncaught ReferenceError: TEST**

With `var` **Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token: '.'**

Comment: @vee: Yes. The assumption is that `var TEST=TEST || {};` exists, as per the example in the question.

Answer (score 6):

Generally this is exactly what ES6 modules are for:

```
export class Test2 { ... }

...

import * as TEST from './test';

new TEST.Test2(...)
```

For a single file with class definitions, it can be

```
const TEST = window.TEST || {};

{
  class Test2 { ... }
  ...

  Object.assign(TEST, { Test2, ... });
}
```

Another option is using class expressions (as another answer already explained).